# Angular 4 directive error: Can't resolve all parameters for directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm totally new to Angular and trying to inject [basic structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-myunless-property) from Angular guide. Here is my directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[pcDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  private hasView = false;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private items
  ) { }

  @Input() set pcDropdown(condition: boolean) {
    if (!condition && !this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      this.hasView = true;
    } else if (condition && this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.hasView = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to inject it in my `TradeModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { TradeComponent } from './trade.component';
import { DropdownDirective } from '../dropdown.directive/dropdown.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [TradeComponent, DropdownDirective],
  exports: [DropdownDirective]
})
export class TradeModule { }
```

And use the following part of HTML in my `TradeComponent`'s template:

```
...
<p *pcDropdown="true">
  TEST
</p>
...
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DropdownDirective:
>   ([object Object], [object Object], ?).

Webstorm is also underlying my `@Directive` decorator and say the following:

> Angular: Can't resolve all parameters for DropdownDirective in
>   /home/commercialsuicide/Desktop/my-app/src/client/app/dropdown.directive/dropdown.directive.ts:
>   ([object Object], [object Object], ?)

[image]

It also say that my `pcDropdown` input is unused:

[image]

Need to say, that i already saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42717565/6053654) and `emitDecoratorMetadata` is already set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`.

Please, point where I misspelled or forgot to include something in my code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`private items` is missing a type parameter. Angular can't create component instances if it can't resolve all parameters to providers.
Resolving to providers only works with parameter types and `@Inject(...)` annotations.

If you don't want `items` to be injected, remove the parameter. There is no situation where you would need to create a component instance yourself to pass the parameter explicitely.

Comment: Hm, the solution is very basic. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hint: The error message points it out with the `?` which parameter causes the error `DropdownDirective: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).`. Glad to hear this solved it for you already :)

Comment: for those very new to Angular, any classes that have the core decorators (e.g. `@Component`, `@Directive`, `@Injectable`, etc) will have any parameters in the Constructor filled in (aka Injected) by Angular when instantiated using the specified _type_.   Make sure that what ever parameters you declare in the constructor of these classes is another [core decorated] Class (e.g. a Service/Directive/Component class).  There are other ways to get around this by defining and injector.  I suggest reading these docs https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection a few times over.

Answer (score 0):

I just left my case here, because found just this question by my request.

I had annotation @HostListener and onResize method. @HostListener should be before and close to the related method. Like

```
@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
onResize(event) {
    // some code
}
```

I got this error when had moved annotation before calling another method. Like

```
@HostListener("window:resize", ["$event"])
getSomeObjects (args:any = {}) {
    // some code
}

onResize(event) {
    // some code
}
```

Hope, this will be helpful for somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, in my case was because I have a service named `Storage`, but the compiler won't mark it as error, because javascript have a global variable named the same. So I just added:

```
import { Storage } from '@core/auth/token-storage.service';
```